# How to correctly format an online source with long URL in Bibtex

Tags: bibtex

I have the following online source (URL) and I created a BibTex entry out of it

```
@online{verbraucherzentrale2023,
  title = {Energieausweis: Was sagt dieser Steckbrief für Wohngebäude aus?},
  author = {{Verbraucherzentrale NRW e.V.}},
  year = {2023},
  url = {https://www.verbraucherzentrale.de/wissen/energie/energetische-sanierung/energieausweis-was-sagt-dieser-steckbrief-fuer-wohngebaeude-aus-24074},
}
```

Here is the output
[image]

There are 2 problems:

1. The title is a link to the URL (and thus blue). It should just be a title without a link.
2. The URL spans over the borders of the paper. This should not be the case. It should be prevented by doing a linebreak at the correct position

Do you know how I have to adjust the bibtex entry to get rid of those 2 problems?

Update: Here is the main Latex file

```
\documentclass[5p,times,twocolumn]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hidelinks}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{amssymb}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amssymb
\usepackage{pifont}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pifont
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}%
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}%
\usepackage{acro}
\include{sections/00_acro}
\graphicspath{{figures/}}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{framed} % Framing content
\usepackage{multicol} % Multiple columns environment
\usepackage{nomencl} % Nomenclature package

\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{xurl}

%Define the color of the links
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\definecolor{myColor}{RGB}{0, 0.0, 0} 

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=myColor,
    citecolor=myColor,
    urlcolor=myColor,
}

\journal{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{Title}


\author[1]{Author 1}
\author[1]{Author 2}


\address[1]{Institue 1}

\begin{abstract}
\input{sections/00_abstract}
\end{abstract}

\begin{comment}
%%Graphical abstract
\begin{graphicalabstract}
\includegraphics{grabs}
\end{graphicalabstract}

%%Research highlights
\begin{highlights}
\item Research highlight 1
\item Research highlight 2
\end{highlights}
\end{comment}




\begin{keyword}
%% keywords here, in the form: keyword \sep keyword
keyword 1 \sep keyword 2 \sep keyword 3 \sep keyword 4 \sep keyword 5 
%% PACS codes here, in the form: \PACS code \sep code
%\PACS 0000 \sep 1111
%% MSC codes here, in the form: \MSC code \sep code
%% or \MSC[2008] code \sep code (2000 is the default)
%MSC 0000 \sep 1111
\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}

\thispagestyle{empty} % Remove page number and header/footer on the first page

%% \linenumbers

%\input{sections/00_nomecl}
\input{sections/01_intro}
\input{sections/02_results}
\input{sections/03_conclusion}


%% If you have bibdatabase file and want bibtex to generate the
%% bibitems, please use
%%
 \bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num} 
 \bibliography{refs}

%% else use the following coding to input the bibitems directly in the
%% TeX file.

% \begin{thebibliography}{00}

% %% \bibitem{label}
% %% Text of bibliographic item

% \bibitem{}

% \end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
\endinput
%%
%% End of file `elsarticle-template-num.tex'.
```

Comment: Your document (you should always provide an example such taht we know exactly what you are doing) seems to be using the `url` package, try loading the `xurl` package instead as it allows more linebreaking possibilities.

Comment: @daleif: Thanks dalaeif for your answer. I did what you suggested and the line-break problem is resolved. However, the problem Nr. 1 (title is a link) still persists. Further, like in the other package, after "URL" there is no ":" which I think looks bad. How can I change that?

Comment: You have provided no code and no information about the bib style being used. So how exactly are we suppose to help? ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @daleif: Thanks for your comment. I uploaded the main latex file

Comment: Please note that this example is not selfcontained. It refers to files we do not have, so we cannot test it.

Comment: what exactly do you need? I am using overleaf with a template for a journal. I has 7 style files that can have up to 1500 lines of code (and that I am not allowed to change and most probably not allow to share). So maybe you can just suggest one approach how to get rid of the 2 problems

Comment: If you have been asked to use a template and the template gives problems like that, it is not your job to fix it. The people maintaining the template need to fix it. As long as you cannot provide a self contained example there is not much we can do. You specifically do not need all those `\input` in an example you want others to test.

Comment: As for the link on the title that is a part of the bibtex style. It cannot be removed without some hacking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too long for a comment, but this seems to replicate your first image in one single file

```
\documentclass[5p,times,twocolumn]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hidelinks}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{amssymb}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amssymb
\usepackage{pifont}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pifont
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}%
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}%
\usepackage{acro}
\include{sections/00_acro}
\graphicspath{{figures/}}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{framed} % Framing content
\usepackage{multicol} % Multiple columns environment
\usepackage{nomencl} % Nomenclature package

\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{xurl}

%Define the color of the links
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\definecolor{myColor}{RGB}{0, 0.0, 0} 

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=myColor,
    citecolor=myColor,
    urlcolor=myColor,
}

\journal{}


\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{refs.bib}
@online{verbraucherzentrale2023,
  title = {Energieausweis: Was sagt dieser Steckbrief für Wohngebäude aus?},
  author = {{Verbraucherzentrale NRW e.V.}},
  year = {2023},
  url = {https://www.verbraucherzentrale.de/wissen/energie/energetische-sanierung/energieausweis-was-sagt-dieser-steckbrief-fuer-wohngebaeude-aus-24074},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\cite{verbraucherzentrale2023}

\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num} 
\bibliography{refs}
\end{document}
```

Question 2 is easy to answer, use `xurl` as you do in the example. It introduces more break points than the normal `url`.

For Question 1, this comes from the bibtex style being used `elsarticle-num.bst`. It wraps the title in `\href{url}{title}`. There does not seem to be any method of turning this off.

One can do

```
\renewcommand\href[2]{#2}
```

before the bibliography. But, if you have been asked to use a specific template and an spacific bibtex style, you really should not change the formatting.

Comment: @dalaeif. Thanks a lot dalaeif for your answer. Can I not just tell Latex to not use a link in the title for that specific bibtex entry? Maybe I can adjust the bibtex entry itself to do that? Further, is there a way to make a ":" after the "URL"?

Comment: @PeterBe that will be overwritten the next time you run bibtex. If you've been asked to use this style, then don't fight it, it is not your call. I've been on the receiving end and it is super annoying when users change the template or layout or font when they have been explicitly told not so.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Well actually, the template looks horrible. I have never seen a title being a link. Further, the linebreaks in the Bibtex entry are as awful as it can get. So there is an urgent need to change the template. It's erroneous and ridicilous and far away from looking good.

Comment: Remember that often journals will not use what you submit, but rather convert it into an in house design. The linking and line break might be for easier peer review. Nobody knows why these look like they do. For articles it is just not worth fighting